# Do spaces satisfying the first axiom of countability have monotone decreasing bases for every point?

Tags: general-topology

I'm facing some problems with this. Every proof I've read assumes this, although it is not obvious to me as of now.

First axiom of countability as defined in my book- *for every point $x\in X$, there is a countable family of open sets $\{B_{n}(x)\}$ ($n\in\mathbb{N}$) such that for any open set $G$ containing $x$, there is a $B_{n}\subseteq G$.*

Why isn't it possible that $B_{i}$ and $B_{j}$ be intersecting (both contain $x$), but one is not a subset of the other? $i\neq j$ and $i,j\in\mathbb{N}$.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: I think the $B_n$ are required to contain $x$. Otherwise picking $B_n = \varnothing$ would make every space first countable.

Comment: True. Stupid mistake on my part. The last line was added rather rashly and in a hurry...the edit has been made. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Abel mentioned, they can not be disjoint sa they have to contain $x$.

Even though, the definition does not require $\{B_n\}_{n\in N}$ to be decreasing. One can choose them to be decreasing by setting:

$$C_i=\cap_{j=1}^iB_j$$

It follows that $\{C_i\}$ is a decreasing sequence of open sets that satisfy:

for any open set $G$ containing $x$, there exists $n$ such that $C_{n}\subseteq G$.

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks tons.

Comment: @AyushKhaitan You are welcome !